# Read N lines from file and save it to new file

Tags: java, file, file-io, text-files

How to make, for example, to read 20 lines from `readFile` or n lines and to save it to another file (`writeFile`)?

```
public class Test_read_file {
  public static List<String> readFile() throws IOException {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\Admin\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\Work Files\\\\\\\\314-WO0000001133814\\\\\\\\Cards\\\\\\\\MBD10760_182.out"))){
        List<String> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();
        String d;
        while((d = br.readLine()) != null){
            listOfData.add(d);
        }
        return listOfData;
    }
}

public static void writeFile(List<String> listOfData) throws IOException{
    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\Admin\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\Work Files\\\\\\\\314-WO0000001133814\\\\\\\\Cards\\\\\\\\MBD10760_187.out"))){
        for(String str: listOfData){
            bw.write(str);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> data = readFile();
    writeFile(data);
}
}
```

Comment: Figure out how to do this from a command line app. and it will be easy to integrate that into a desktop app. In other words, this has nothing to do with Swing. Please choose tags carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the assumption of your code is working correct:

```
public static List<String> readFile(int n) throws IOException {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader("C:\\\\\\\\Users\\\\\\\\Admin\\\\\\\\Desktop\\\\\\\\Work Files\\\\\\\\314- 
WO0000001133814\\\\\\\\Cards\\\\\\\\MBD10760_182.out"))){
        List<String> listOfData = new ArrayList<>();
        String d;
        while((d = br.readLine()) != null && n>0){
            listOfData.add(d);
            n--;
        }
        return listOfData;
    }
```

Just you have to tell the loop how many lines should it read. If file has less than n lines,then first statement of while loop will return null and it will break the loop. Otherwise, when it reads n number of lines,it will again break the loop thanks to second statement in while loop.

Comment: How to make it  to read this n number or n to be given by variable?

Comment: If you look at method signature, I gave it with method parameter.

Comment: yeah i made it,now i need to implement this in java swing gui i think i will works with this code

Answer (score 1):

Just add to while checking of listOfData size:

```java
 while( ((d = br.readLine()) != null) && listOfData.size()<20 ) {
            listOfData.add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Path pathFrom = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Work Files\\314-WO0000001133814\\Cards\\MBD10760_182.out\"");
     Path pathTo = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Work Files\\314-WO0000001133814\\Cards\\MBD10760_187.out\"");
     Files.write(pathTo, Files.lines(pathFrom).limit(20).collect(Collectors.toList()));
 }
```

Comment: `readAllLines()` literally reads all lines. It could be a performance issue when the input file is large. Probably a better solution would be to use the Stream API (provided the OP can use Java 8) and just `limit()` to the desired line count.